# passing multiple arguments cmd vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i searched google and stackoverflow alot but no solution

i was trying to pass multiple arguments in cmd 
they are like in this way

```
Dim argu1 As String = "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode = allow  ssid=" + TextBox1.Text + " key=" + TextBox2.Text
    Dim argu2 As String = "netsh wlan start hostednetwork"
    Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing
    Dim processStartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    processStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    processStartInfo.Verb = "runas"
```

and wrote arguments in this way

```
    processStartInfo.Arguments = argu1 & argu2
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    Try
        process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unknown Error !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If Not (process Is Nothing) Then
            process.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
```

but nothing is happening

so plz tell me how can i pass multiple arguments

Answer (score 3):

What did you expect to happen? You are executing

```
cmd.exe netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode = allow  ssid=... key=...netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

which simply starts a new instance of cmd.exe, ignoring all that `netsh ...` stuff.

Please [have a look at the documentation of cmd.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx). In particular, I suspect that the `/c` command line switch might be what you are looking for. That said, you might want to consider calling netsh.exe directly or (even better) search for a way to do what you are trying to achieve with Windows API or the .NET library.